# Get property by dynamic key name?

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to avoid duplicating some templates, let's say I have the following (very simplified) template:

```
<div class="same-template">
    @(button?.buttonLeft.Url)
</div>
<div class="same-template">
    @(button?.buttonRight.Url)
</div>
```

I also have a button Right template as well, so my question is, is there a way I can pass in the "Side" of the button, and access the property? I know in javascript I'd do something like:

`@(button?.button"+side+".Url)` but obviously we're not using javascript.

I've tried creating a helper function

```
@helper GetFooter(Object button, String side) {
    <div class="same-template">
        <!-- don't know what to do here... -->
        @(button?.button<side>.Url)
    </div>
}

@GetFooter(button, "Right")
```

I hope this was clear enough!

**EDIT:**
   Ive made the following function, however on some it fails on the `var b` line with the following error:

`Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
@functions{

    public dynamic GetNestedDynamicValue(IContentCardItem cardItem, String first, String second) {
        var b = cardItem?.GetType().GetProperty(first).GetValue(cardItem, null);
        var c = b?.GetType().GetProperty(second).GetValue(b, null);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you want to present value of button's property in page? And you want to access to that property by string name?

Comment: The way you want to access the property is not supported. What you can do is check the value of `side`  in if clause and use appropriate property of button based on the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is typed and doesn't provide functionalities like JavaScript. Anyway, you can try something like in follwoing example to dinamically read value of property by name:

```
<div>
    @(button?.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyNameWhichYouNeed").GetValue(button, null))
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Ok, I am think that you will need some extension method, but try first this:

```
button?.GetType().GetProperty("buttonRight").GetValue(button, null)
    .GetType().GetProperty("Url").GetValue(
button?.GetType().GetProperty("buttonRight").GetValue(button, null),
 null);
```

It became confusing :) I don't like this kind of UI but let try to explain:

Firs I retrieve type of `buttonRight` property. Then I retrieve type `Url` and supplied type of `buttonRight` instance.

It should be broken in following lines:

```
var buttonRight = button.GetType().GetProperty("buttonRight").GetValue(button, null);
var url = buttonRight.GetType().GetProperty("Url").GetValue(buttonRight, null);
```

Now `url` is value which you looking. Please see on fiddle how it works:

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qVaoiy).

Comment: Thanks for this, This is similar to what I've tried, I completely omitted part of my code, how would I access `button?.buttonLeft?.Text`, where Left is still the dynamic part of the key, but Text is the constant?

Comment: Thanks for this, one last thing! I've edited my OP again with my last problem

Comment: I latest edit: It looks like that cannot construct object for `first` or `second`. Can you make sure that these properties exists? Can you do some logging or debugging? Here is fiddle for my case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qVaoiy